# Cloudformation Template format error: Every DeletionPolicy member must be a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Hi I am trying to use the "IF" Function just like mentioned in cloud formation documentation for RDS DeletionPolicy, but for some reason it says that my function does not return a string.

[AWS Documentation on conditional statements](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#d0e92611)

here is the condition:

```
 "DeletionPolicy" : {
    "Fn::If" : [
      "CreateProdResources",
      "Snapshot",
      "Delete"
    ]}
```

And the error is the one in the title:

```
Template validation error: Template format error: Every DeletionPolicy member must be a string.
```

Other attempts that didn't work:

With a map:

```
 "RdsDeletionPolicyMap" :{
      "production" : {
          "policy" : "Snapshot"
      },
      "staging" : {
          "policy" : "Delete"
      }
   }
```

And then:

```
   "DeletionPolicy" : {
      "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RdsDeletionPolicyMap", {"Ref": "RailsEnvironment"}, "policy" ]
   }
```

As well as a Simple `"Ref": ...` didn't work as well. I highly suspect this is a bug with cloudformation

Comment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/162

Answer (score 28):

The issue is that DeletionPolicy must be set to one of three strings.  And, though your If check will return one of them, from a systematic perspective, it only knows that it's returning a String - but is not guaranteed to be a valid string (same with your map and parameter checks), and thus it only accepts a string literal and not something that resolves to string.

I believe that this limitation has been raised to the AWS Engineering team previously, as it is a nuisance.

Comment: IMO this is most definitely a bug. Any ideas on how to work around it?

Comment: You could add a conditional statement and have 2 retention policies with the appropriate one being added based on the condition.  Definitely non-ideal.

Comment: Thanks, ill see what i can make of it

Comment: This is unbelievably annoying. I just ran into the same thing, 6 years later. Amazing they haven't fixed it yet.

Answer (score 4):

This is now supported if you use the [`AWS::LanguageExtensions` transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-aws-languageextensions.html); read [Intrinsic function references in DeletionPolicy and UpdateReplacePolicy attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/function-refs-in-policy-attributes.html). This was originally raised in [Support Functions as DeletionPolicy/UpdateReplacePolicy Values #58](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-language-discussion/issues/58), tracked in  [Tracking Issue: Allow Intrinsic Functions and Pseudo-Parameter References in DeletionPolicy and UpdateReplacePolicy RFC #11](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-language-discussion/issues/11), and apparently implemented in [RFC 0011: Allow Intrinsic Functions and Pseudo-Parameter References in DeletionPolicy and UpdateReplacePolicy RFC #74](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-language-discussion/pull/74).

Basically you need to put `Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions` at the top of your CloudFormation template like this:

```yaml
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions

Description: My CloudFormationTemplate

…
```

Unfortunately it still doesn't work in all cases; see [Use CloudFormation import with substitution name in conditional expression with `DeletionPolicy`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76484686) . A ticket has been filed to improve this by allowing imports in conditions: [Use Fn::ImportValue in Conditions #127](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-language-discussion/issues/127).

Comment: Finally makes it work, thank you Garret!

Answer (score 3):

According to intrensic-function-referece
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html

> You can use intrinsic functions only in specific parts of a template.
>   Currently, you can use intrinsic functions in resource properties,
>   outputs, metadata attributes, and update policy attributes. You can
>   also use intrinsic functions to conditionally create stack resources.

So you cannot use them for the DeletionPolicy

However, one workaround for this is Cloudformation conditionals: https://www.unixdaemon.net/cloud/intro-to-cloudformations-conditionals/

You can add two resources with the condition and each having snapshot and delete in each resource.

Answer (score -1):

Yes intrinsic functions are allowed to be used only in a certain places. And also within an intrinsic function, only a set of predefined intrinsic functions can be used. You can try [cloudkast](https://krunal4amity.github.io) which is an online cloudformation template generator which makes it very easy to create cloudformation templates.