# How to set a DeletionPolicy from Parameters in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to adapt my DeletionPolicy in my CloudFormation template:

```
        "DeletionPolicy":{
            "Fn::If":[
                "ShouldRetain",
                "Retain",
                "Delete"
            ]
        }
```

Though I get:

```
Template format error: Every DeletionPolicy member must be a string.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloudformation Template format error: Every DeletionPolicy member must be a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286395/cloudformation-template-format-error-every-deletionpolicy-member-must-be-a-stri)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, the "DeletionPolicy" parameter must take a string literal only. Anything that resolve to a string such as from mapping or parameters is not possible. This is limitation from AWS.

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation!

Comment: See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=560586 for a half decade of the cloudformation team ignoring the limitation (2014: "I've passed your sentiment onto the engineering team so that they're aware of your use cases").

Comment: Sigh still an issue in 2019

Comment: And in 2021, apparently,

Comment: yes, at least December 2021

Comment: … and also June 2022

Comment: ... and also in October 2022

Comment: It works now- 
Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/function-refs-in-policy-attributes.html

Comment: It works now only with silly work arounds of having to specify a transform for the template, but yes at least there is a relatively workable solution now.