# (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: Every Description member must be a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

The following image is my question. SO would not allow me to post because of some error about formatting code incorrectly that I couldn't figure out how to resolve after an hour of trying.

[Image of my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7lwa.png)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've been bitten by this too. It boils down to limitations on CloudFormation's intrinsic functions **([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html))**:

> **Note**
>   You can use intrinsic functions only in specific parts of a template. Currently, you can use intrinsic functions in ***resource properties***, metadata attributes, and update policy attributes.

In this case, "resource properties" only applies to the contents of the Properties field. I would expect this to change, since I suspect Amazon has gotten many complaints about this! I'll happily update the answer when that happens.

Comment: Seems like this is still happening, even after a year.  Hopefully AWS will support this soon.

Comment: Still needs a string literal as of January 2018.

Answer (score 4):

The `Description` must be a literal string value. Even if it is an expression that returns a string, such as the one you have, it is invalid. Here is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34286395/1428388).

Comment: I did see that post, but I figured because my situation was for both a different function and a different property that it was still worth asking. I still don't understand; if properties don't accept returned strings, then what is even the point of having functions that return strings?