# Use CloudFormation import with substitution name in conditional expression with `DeletionPolicy`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

One of my AWS CloudFormation templates exports a value for "stage" (which can be e.g. "dev" or "prod") in a variable based upon the stack name, like this:

```yaml
Export:
  …
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}:stage"
```

The stack name is in the form `foo-${Env}`, where `Env` is some value such as "bar". This `Env` param is passed to another CloudFormation template. The other template should be able to access the stage of that `Env` like this, using the external export:

```yaml
      SomeResourceProperty:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub "foo-${Env}:stage"
```

For example if the `Env` parameter is set to "bar", this would pull in the external variable `foo-bar:stage`. And that's no problem. It works fine. I import all sorts of variables from the first stack using this form.

I would like to create a condition based upon this variable, in order to set the retention of a resource based upon the stage. First I try this:

```yaml
Conditions:
  IsStageProd: !Equals
    - Fn::ImportValue:
        !Sub "foo-${Env}:stage"
    - "prod"
```

CloudFormation whimpers and tells me that it can't use imported values in conditions.

Never mind; I'll import the value directly in my `!If` function. [As per Intrinsic function references in DeletionPolicy and UpdateReplacePolicy attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/function-refs-in-policy-attributes.html), I add the `AWS::LanguageExtensions` transformation:

```yaml
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions

…
```

Then I try to set the deletion policy of a log group:

```yaml
    DeletionPolicy:
      Fn::If:
        - Fn::Equals:
            - Fn::ImportValue:
                !Sub "foo-${Env}:stage"
            - "prod"
        - Retain
        - Delete
```

This time CloudFormation breaks down in tears:

> `Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: Transform AWS::LanguageExtensions failed with: Fn::If layout is incorrect`

How can I conditionally retain a resource based upon the value of a variable imported from another stack, when the name of the variable depends on a parameter passed to the current template?

I have filed [Use CloudFormation import with substitution name in conditional expression with DeletionPolicy. #126](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-language-discussion/issues/126).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a limitation. A ticket for improvement has been filed as [Use Fn::ImportValue in Conditions #127](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-language-discussion/issues/127).